# Validating custom webpart property set by a custom toolpart?

Tags: web-part, toolpart

I'm building a custom web part with a custom toolpart to edit its custom properties.

I'm wondering where should I valide the values.

I can see two places where I can validate.

Either in the property itself:

```
    private int? m_MaxNumberOfSomething;

    [Browsable(false)]
    [Category(Constants.WebPartsExtendedPropertiesCategoryName)]
    [DefaultValue(5)]
    [WebPartStorage(Storage.Personal)]
    public int? MaxNumberOfSomething
    {
        get
        {
            return m_MaxNumberOfSomething;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.HasValue && value < 1) throw new WebPartPageUserException("At least one !");
            m_MaxNumberOfSomething = value;
        }
    }
```

Or in the apply changes of the toolpart method :

```
    public override void ApplyChanges()
    {
        int maxNumberOfSomething;
        if (!int.TryParse(txtMaxNumberOfSomething.Text, out maxNumberOfSomething))
        {
            throw new WebPartPageUserException("At least one");
        }
        ParentWebPart.MaxNumberOfSomething = maxNumberOfSomething;
    }
```

Is there any 3rd way?

What is the correct place to add such validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in the `set`ter.

As you are throwing an Exception anyways it is cleaner to not let the user `set` the value in the first place. If you would do validation only in the `ApplyChanges` method, other code might have worked with the already wrongly set value.

Validate in `set`, so the user isn't even allowed to write invalid stuff to your variable. [Here is a blog post showing exactly that method](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2010/06/validating-web-part-properties.html), but you do it correctly anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, what about complex validation? For example, imagine i have two integer properties, `A` and `B` and a rule that states `A+B` must be less than 100?

Comment: Well the validation in the WebPart Properties are very "stupid". Throwing an exception for a validation error? I don't think that's clean. As for your example where one value depends on the value of the other: I would do *that* in the `ApplyChanges` method as it involves multiple fields. If you're talking about a single field, do it in the setter.